# Theorem 3.2.14 (Probability: Theory and Examples, Durrett, 5th ed.)

Tags: probability-theory

The proof of the theorem is a single line and thus seemingly straightforward, yet I cannot see how to justify it. I tried to rearrange some of the pieces, but that approach failed to improve my understanding. Any help in justifying the statement would be greatly appreciated.

$\textbf{Theorem 3.2.14.}$
If there is a $\varphi\ge0$ so that $\varphi(x)\to\infty$ as $|x|\to\infty$ and
$$
C=\sup_n\int\varphi(x)dF_n(x)<\infty,
$$
then $F_n$ is tight.

$\textbf{Proof.}$
$$
1-F_n(M)+F_n(-M)\le\frac{C}{\inf_{|x|\ge M}\varphi(x)}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Durret's book is good but sometimes you find thigs like these. Anyway He's using $$\text { Theorem 1.6.4. Chebyshev's inequality. Suppose } \varphi: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R} \text { has }  \varphi \geq 0 \text { , let } A \in \mathcal{R} \text { and let } \; i_{A}=\inf \{\varphi(y): y \in A\}. \;\; \text{ Then } \; i_{A} P(X \in A) \leq E(\varphi(X) ; X \in A) \leq E \varphi(X)$$

So you write $A:=\{|x|\geq M\}$. You have that $$\inf_{|x|\ge M}\varphi(x)\cdot \big(1-F_n(M)+F_n(-M)\big)= i_A P(X_n\in A)\leq E (\varphi(X_n))=\int \varphi(x)F_n(dx)<C$$

So if $\varepsilon>0$ you can found $M$ big enough in such way that $\frac{C}{\inf_{|x|\ge M}\varphi(x)}<\varepsilon$ and you finished.

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight! I had been reviewing some material on tightness and realized that I could not prove the result myself, at least not in the way formulated by Durrett. Now, thanks to you, it's all clear!

Comment: I was familiar with Chebyshev’s inequality, but only in the formulation, as Durrett remarks following the theorem you cite, for the special case.